# Image Slicer not working past first slice - Pillow

Tags: python, image, split, python-imaging-library, slice

So, I'm working on my very first non-game project and my goal is to create a basic image slicer. The idea is that I want to take an image, receive user input for the size of a slice, and then break the image down into the correct amount of slices. My code is currently creating the correct amount of slices and the first slice appears to be correct, but remaining slices are all either blank images or full alpha images.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
 

im = Image.open("48x48.png")

print('Enter your desired tile size in pixels (Example: 16 will be a 16x16 tile):')
tilesize = input()
tilesize = int(tilesize)

rows = im.size[0] / tilesize
cols = im.size[1] / tilesize

ir = 0
ic = 0
while ir != rows:
    while ic != cols:
        box = (0 + ic * tilesize, 0 + ir * tilesize, tilesize + ic * tilesize, tilesize + ir * tilesize)
        region = im.crop(box)
        slice = Image.new('RGBA', (tilesize, tilesize), color=255)
        mask=Image.new('L', slice.size, color=255)
        draw=ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
        draw.rectangle((0,0,tilesize,tilesize), fill=0)
        slice.putalpha(mask)
        slice.paste(region, box)
        outfile = "r" + str(ir+1) + "c" + str(ic+1) + ".png"
        slice.save(outfile)
        ic += 1
    ir +=1
    ic = 0
```

I'm using the Pillow library for this, by the way. Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got some help on another forum. I had to replace slice.paste(region, box) with slice.paste(region, (0,0)). Success!